# Help showing that two sets are equal.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions, elementary-set-theory, set-theory

Let $A,B\in\mathbb{N}$ and define
$$\tag{1}
U(A, B):=\{K \subseteq \mathbb{N} \mid A \subseteq K \subseteq \mathbb{N} \backslash B\} \subseteq 2^{\mathbb{N}}
$$
Define further $f: 2^{\mathbb{N}} \rightarrow \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\{0,1\}$ by
$$\tag{2}
f(A)_{n}:=\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
1 & \text { for } & n \in A \\
0 & \text { for } & n \notin A
\end{array}\right.
$$
I want to show that
$$\tag{3}
\left(\mathrm{pr}_{m} \circ f\right)^{-1}(\{1\})=U(\{m\}, \emptyset)
$$
where $\text{pr}_m$ is the projection operator. It is pretty clear that $U(\{m\},\emptyset)$ consists of all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ that contain $m$. However $\left(p r_{m} \circ f\right)(X)=\{1\}$ is true whenever the sets in $X$ contain $m$ - this (to me) appears to be true regardless of how many sets $X$ contains, in which case $pr_m\circ f$ is not bijective. Where am I going wrong here?

**Edit**: I am suppost to use eq. $(3)$ as well as
$$\tag{4}
\left(\mathrm{pr}_{m} \circ f\right)^{-1}(\{0\})=U(\emptyset,\{m\})
$$
to show that the function $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Yes, $\operatorname{pr}_m \circ f$ is not bijective, since it's a function from $2^\mathbb{N}$ to $\{0,1\}$. And $(\operatorname{pr}_m \circ f)(X)$ only makes sense when $X$ is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$, so "the sets in $X$ contain $m$" isn't right.

Comment: @aschepler, Of course, a function from $2^{\mathbb{N}}$ to ${0,1}$ cannot be bijective; I should have realized that straight away. It was part of an assignment to prove eq. $(3)$, which is why I got confused.